# My text looks metallic and reflective on Material preview mode, but not on render view mode

Tags: shaders, text-object

So I'm trying to make a simple animation for the "Avengers" text logo.
I'm trying to make the border of the letters metallic and silvery and the center of the letters Red.
In Material view mode, this is how it looks like:
[image: Material mode view]

Which looks great.
But in Render mode, that's how it looks like:
[image: Render Mode View]

I tried keeping it simple as much as I can, so I just used my materials tab.
This is how it looks like in the shading tab:
[image: Material tab view]

Lastly, these are my render settings:

[image: Render settings]

I'd Appreciate any help. I'm new to blender and I feel like I'm missing something very basic.

Comment: Material preview uses a hidden HDRI Environment texture to aid the viewability of reflections - there is no such texture enabled by default in the render preview (so glossy surfaces only reflect the grey background and look flat). To fix, you must add your own HDRI texture (in the world shader). Blender comes with some and they are kept in the blender folder at  _.../4.0/datafiles/studiolights/world_. The one used in material preview is _forest.exr_. You can also find many free ones online - one of the most popular places is Poly Haven - https://polyhaven.com/hdris